# Facebook's Flashcache writeback block cache

Tags: cache, innodb

Im quite interested in Facebook's code which was thrown over the wall again..

[FlashCache](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=388112370932) ...

Sounds fast, using SSD's to help scale InnoDB/MySQL, but it was designed as a generic caching module that can be used with any application built on top of any block device..

Anyone tried it? Or using it?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out the benchmarks of Flashcache on mysqlperformanceblog.com - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/?s=flashcache

Binaries of Percona Server (MySQL fork) with Flashcache support are on the product roadmap, located here:
http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-server:roadmap

(Disclaimer: I work for Percona, authors of mysqlperformanceblog.com)